# Adobe Pdf - Hiding buttons on PNG export

Tags: pdf, adobe

Good Day,
I'm creating a form in Adobe and need to use the form exported as an image. However, when exporting, the buttons appear in the output image. I was wondering if there is a way to hide the buttons when exporting the from as an PNG image.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your button before exporting it to an image.

Comment: Your mean to hide the buttons every time I wanna export the form to an image and show them back in the form for the next use?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Since there were not very helpful answers to my question and after searching the web for a while, according to help desk link below, the buttons can be invisible except for a rollover act that make them visible. This way the when the form is exported as an image the unwanted buttons like "Form Reset" will not be exported to the image and yet it's there to reset the form.

[Hide an Acrobat button except during rollover](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html)